# Writing a factorial function in ARM assembly language

Tags: algorithms

I am required to write a factorial function in ARM assembly language that takes an integer $ n $ as input and returns the value of $ n! $. However, I can only use the $ 4 $ basic arithmetic operations $ + - * / $ (so no if-else or loop or recursion). Can anyone suggest a hint to do that? I can only do if I am allowed to use if-else or recursion.

Comment: Any other available operations? Read, write, compare etc.?

Comment: Think about how you would define the factorial function recursively as a mathematical function, then implement that. But "How do I code X in language Y?" is off-topic at [cs.se].

Answer (score 1):

we were required to do something similar. We were given a number to calculate, which was 7!.r0 will hold the final value. I ended up doing the following:

MOV r1, #7
MOV r1, #6
MOV r1, #5
MOV r1, #4
MOV r1, #3
MOV r1, #2
MOV r1, #1

MUL r0, r1, r2
MUL r0, r0, r3
MUL r0, r0, r4
MUL r0, r0, r5
MUL r0, r0, r6
MUL r0, r0, r7